# Per Pixel 2D circular collision Detection in SDL

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu, sdl, collision-detection

Alrighty well straight to it, I'm using [this](http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson18/index.php) guide as I learn SDL and I'm having difficulties with the per pixel collision part. My implementation to this is slightly different to the guides and it is causing some unwanted issues. The issue being the moving ball goes straight through the stationary ball (it's meant to be solid and block the moving ball as you might expect). I know that the rectangular collision boxes are in the proper places because I've recoloured the moving ball to be white (the ball.bmp is loaded red in colour) and the stationary ball to be blue, The collision boxes on top of each ball has been recoloured.

My Collision detection function is as follow

```
bool checkCol(std::vector<SDL_Rect> A,std::vector<SDL_Rect> B){
    int TOP1,           TOP2;
    int BOTTOM1,    BOTTOM2;
    int LEFT1,          LEFT2;
    int RIGHT1,     RIGHT2;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++){
        TOP1         =      A[ i ].y;
        BOTTOM1  =      A[ i ].y + A[ i ].h;
        LEFT1        =      A[ i ].x;
        RIGHT1       =      A[ i ].x + A[ i ].w;
        for (int j = 0; j < B.size(); j++){
            TOP2         =      B[ i ].y;
            BOTTOM2  =      B[ i ].y + B[ i ].h;
            LEFT2        =      B[ i ].x;
            RIGHT2       =      B[ i ].x + B[ i ].w;

            if ( RIGHT1 <= LEFT2 ){ return false; }
            if ( LEFT1 >= RIGHT2 ){ return false; }
            if ( TOP1 >= BOTTOM2 ){ return false; }
            if ( BOTTOM1 <= TOP2 ){ return false; }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

[here](http://www.datafilehost.com/download-593b4e38.html) is the full source code(too large to post here) and executable(linux).

Could someone please tell me where I've gone wrong?.

[edit]
Ignore the rectangle in the middle.

Comment: How often do you check these balls for collision? I mean, there might be a situation when on the first frame balls are not _yet_ colliding, on the next one they're _already_ not colliding. Check their speed and sizes, there should be `speed * timeStep < ballSize`.

Comment: @yurymik I'm not sure I follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the algorithm logic is incorrect. When you have a list of conditions and you want to check that *all of them* are false, you should not do `return false;` as soon as you have found *one* which is false.

Comment: Not really. It checks for separation axis: if you can draw a line between two rects without intersecting them => they are not colliding.